# Setting up AppRTC (WebRTC) on Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, webrtc

I am not able to setup WebRTC on Google App Engine. Here are the steps that I performed to deploy the webrtc app on my Google App Engine Project.

1. Clone https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc on my local system.
2. Copied app.yaml from apprtc/src/app_engine/ to root folder of the local repository
3. Edited app.yaml [Set "application" to my appid "ckwebrtc" on Google App Engine]
4. npm install
5. grunt build
6. appcfg.py --oauth2 update

But I am getting "500 Server Error - The server encountered an error and could not complete your request".

URL - https://ckwebrtc.appspot.com/

Kindly help

Update: This is the error that I am getting:

```
2015-04-16 22:34:26 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', '-u', 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\google_appengine\\appcfg.py', '--oauth2', 'update', u'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\heroku\\ckwebrtc']"
10:34 PM Application: ckwebrtc; version: 2
10:34 PM Host: appengine.google.com
10:34 PM Starting update of app: ckwebrtc, version: 2
10:34 PM Getting current resource limits.
10:34 PM Scanning files on local disk.
10:34 PM Scanned 500 files.
10:35 PM Scanned 1000 files.
10:35 PM Scanned 1500 files.
10:35 PM Scanned 2000 files.
2015-04-16 22:36:05,130 ERROR appcfg.py:1925 Invalid character in filename: node_modules/grunt-htmlhint/node_modules/htmlhint/node_modules/jshint/node_modules/shelljs/test/resources/ls/filename(with)[chars$]^that.must+be-escaped 
10:36 PM Scanned 2500 files.
10:36 PM Scanned 3000 files.
10:36 PM Scanned 3500 files.
10:36 PM Scanned 4000 files.
10:36 PM Scanned 4500 files.
10:36 PM Scanned 5000 files.
10:36 PM Scanned 5500 files.
2015-04-16 22:36:55,687 ERROR appcfg.py:2454 An error occurred processing file '': [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\heroku\\ckwebrtc\\node_modules/grunt-closurecompiler/node_modules/closurecompiler/node_modules/tar/node_modules/fstream/node_modules/rimraf/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/node_modules/brace-expansion/node_modules/balanced-match/test/*.*'. Aborting. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 133, in <module>
  run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 129, in run_file
  execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5468, in <module>
  main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5459, in main
  result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3019, in Run
  self.action(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5115, in __call__
  return method()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3853, in Update
  self._UpdateWithParsedAppYaml(appyaml, self.basepath)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3906, in _UpdateWithParsedAppYaml
  self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, basepath, appyaml, APP_YAML_FILENAME)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3791, in UpdateVersion
  return appversion.DoUpload(paths, openfunc)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2445, in DoUpload
  self._AddFilesThatAreSmallEnough(paths, openfunc)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2537, in _AddFilesThatAreSmallEnough
  for path in paths:
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2680, in FileIterator
  entries = set(os.listdir(os.path.join(base, current_dir)))
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\heroku\\ckwebrtc\\node_modules/grunt-closurecompiler/node_modules/closurecompiler/node_modules/tar/node_modules/fstream/node_modules/rimraf/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/node_modules/brace-expansion/node_modules/balanced-match/test/*.*'
2015-04-16 22:36:55 (Process exited with code 1)
You can close this window now.
```

Comment: What directory are you running the update command from?  When you deploy, you need to specify the path to the app engine files, such as:  <path to sdk>/appcfg.py --oauth2 update ./out/app_engine

Comment: @JeffDeskins I tried to deploy the app using Google App Engine SDK and I am getting an error [I have updated my question and included the error generated during the deployment]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this was a windows problem or not. 
I tried again from [koding.com](https://koding.com/R/campuskarma) (Online Cloud) and was successful in setting up the app.

Here's how I did it.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc.git
```

Edit app.yaml, package.json, mainfest.json etc with your application ID.

```
$ sudo npm install grunt-cli   
$ sudo npm install
$ sudo grunt build
$ sudo python /home/campuskarma/google_appengine/appcfg.py --oauth2 -A ckwebrtc update ./out/app_engine/
```

If you get an error asking for rollback then execute the following command:

```
$ sudo python /home/campuskarma/google_appengine/appcfg.py --oauth2 -A ckwebrtc rollback ./out/app_engine/      
$ sudo python /home/campuskarma/google_appengine/appcfg.py --oauth2 -A ckwebrtc update ./out/app_engine/
```

Each of the command mentioned here should be executed from the root of your application folder. (i.e. the folder where your application is cloned)